# Use map function to create one array from Object that has arrays in it

Tags: javascript, arrays

Using Javascript I am trying to create one array from a JSON object. Problem is is that I am trying to get the acceptedAnswers which is an array. I figured map was the best function for this. However what is returned is an array of arrays. I want to get on array of the values only. Thanks for your help.

**Code**

```
let categories = [
      {
        "categoryID": "1",
        "categoryName": "Fruits with seeds",
        "acceptedAnswers": [
          "2","5"
        ]
      },
      {
        "categoryID": "2",
        "categoryName": "Fruits without seeds",
        "acceptedAnswers": [
          "1","3","4"
        ]
      },
      {
        "categoryID": "3",
        "categoryName": "Blue Fruit",
        "acceptedAnswers": [
          "1"
        ]
      }
    ]
```

**JS**

```
let catAcceptedAnswerArray = categories.map(function (cat) {
 return cat.acceptedAnswers
})
console.log(catAcceptedAnswerArray)
```

Returns:

```
0: ["2","5"]
1: ["1","3","4"]
2: ["1"]
```

I am trying to return:

```
0: ["2","5","1","3","4","1"]
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5fra8tun/1/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`map` isn't the right tool to reach for here. Simply create an array and append each object's entries to it:

```
const result = [];
for (const category of categories) {
    result.push(...category.acceptedAnswers);
}
```

Or if you can't use ES2015+ features, an ES5 version:

```
var result = [];
categories.forEach(function(category) {
    result.push.apply(result, category.acceptedAnswers);
});
```

This assumes there won't be thousands and thousands of `acceptedAnswers`; a single call to `push` has platform-specific limits (but again, they're in the thousands).

Like almost all array operations, it's *possible* to shoehorn this into `reduce`, but you don't gain anything by it:

```
var result = categories.reduce(function(arr, category) {
    arr.push.apply(arr, category.acceptedAnswers);
    return arr;
}, []);
```

Comment: You have my sword.

Comment: Thanks for that it worked as advertised! I used your first example.

Answer (score 2):

With ES6 you can try with:

```
categories
  .map(category => category.acceptedAnswers)
  .reduce((acc, ids) => acc.concat(ids), [])
```

Comment: It's hideously inefficient, but yes, you can. :-)

Comment: *Slightly*. :-) `concat` creates new array too. There's no need for any temporary arrays here.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply reduce the Array to first level after mapping using [`Array#concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)

```js
let categories = [{
    "categoryID": "1",
    "categoryName": "Fruits with seeds",
    "acceptedAnswers": [
      "2", "5"
    ]
  },
  {
    "categoryID": "2",
    "categoryName": "Fruits without seeds",
    "acceptedAnswers": [
      "1", "3", "4"
    ]
  },
  {
    "categoryID": "3",
    "categoryName": "Blue Fruit",
    "acceptedAnswers": [
      "1"
    ]
  }
]

let catAcceptedAnswerArray = categories.map(cat => cat.acceptedAnswers).reduce((acc, val) => acc.concat(val), []);

console.log(catAcceptedAnswerArray)
```